# How to use substring in a querybuilder where clause

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.4

How to use substring in querybuilder :

I tried this:

```
$qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->substring('t0.country',1,2) != 'FR');
```

...

but i have this exception:

> Warning: get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, boolean given

Comment: ok, I tried $qb->andWhere("$qb->expr()->substring('t0.country',1,2) != 'FR'");
i get :
Notice: Undefined property: Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder::$expr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were trying to use the `!=` operator in PHP, which will not work. Instead, wrap the condition in the `neq` function, which tests for inequality.

```
$qb->andWhere(
    $qb->expr()->neq(
        $qb->expr()->substring('t0.country', 1, 2), 
        $qb->expr()->literal('FR')
    )
);
```

See documentation here: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/query-builder.html#the-expr-class

Comment: the same, i get this exception: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 133 near 'FR ORDER BY': Error: 'FR' is not defined